# protect_from_forgery with: :exception where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How does `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` work?

I'd like to edit the code to look at it and learn from it. However, I cannot find where it is placed as in a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can find it here on Github : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c60be72c5243c21303b067c9c5cc398111cf48c8/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L88

```
def protect_from_forgery(options = {})
  self.forgery_protection_strategy = protection_method_class(options[:with] || :null_session)
  self.request_forgery_protection_token ||= :authenticity_token
  prepend_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
end
```

The `with: :exception` is passed to `protection_method_class(:exception)`. Which does :

```
def protection_method_class(name)
  ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ProtectionMethods.const_get(name.to_s.classify)
  rescue NameError
  raise ArgumentError, 'Invalid request forgery protection method, use :null_session, :exception, or :reset_session'
end
```

Then this `ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ProtectionMethods.const_get(name.to_s.classify)`. `name.to_s.classify` here will be `Exception`.

Then you can find:

```
module ProtectionMethods
  class Exception
    def initialize(controller)
      @controller = controller
    end

    def handle_unverified_request
      raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
    end
  end
end
```

All of this sets the way the invalid authenticity will be handled.
Then it sets a `before_action`: `:verify_authenticity_token`.

```
def verify_authenticity_token
  unless verified_request?
    logger.warn "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" if logger
    handle_unverified_request
  end
end
```

Which uses the previously defined strategy:

```
def handle_unverified_request
  forgery_protection_strategy.new(self).handle_unverified_request
end
```

To raise the exception as defined in `Exception`.

Comment: can you possibly explain this in more simple terms?

Comment: This explanation seems pretty much as simple and straightforward as can be.

Comment: Basically, it raises an "Exception" if there isn't sufficient protection, or if there is a CSFR-type request.  The "Exception" is whatever caused the fault to begin with.  This forces Rails to tell you what caused the exception.

Comment: [this article](https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery/) explains well about the vulnerability related to CSRF ( Cross-Site Request Forgery) and how `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` helps.

Comment: @thegauraw ... except "this article" no longer exists.

Comment: i guess this article was meant: [Understanding Rails' protect_from_forgery](https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery.html)